# How can extended snmp agent read text file via shell or python? Gives me permission denied for reading file error

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I have a python script that reads last line of a text file (present in location /home/anas/projects) and prints it. Text file contains a single float value on each line. When i run this python script from terminal, it works fine.
The problem i am having is that i want to use this script with snmp. So i have used snmp extend and added

```
extend    snmp-datarate /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/snmp-feedback.py
```

in /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf file. and when i run this command

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public 127.0.0.1 NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendObjects
```

it gives me following error,
**NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutLine."snmp-datarate".4 = STRING: OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/anas/projects'**

Now i thought that it could eb due to use of python so i also tried shell script, named it ***snmp-agra-datarate.sh***, which only have two lines of code

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $( tail -n 1 /home/anas/projects/6780-log.txt )
```

Running this script from terminal produces the expected output. I then extended snmp with

```
extend    datarate      /usr/local/bin/snmp-agra-datarate.sh
```

then when i try to run snmp walk again. i get similar error
**NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutLine."datarate".2 = STRING: tail: cannot open '/home/anas/projects/6780-log.txt' for reading: Permission denied**

Is there something i am missing in order to read external text file with python or shell for extended snmp agent?
-i am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS and net-snmp v5.8
-Both python and shell scripts have execute permissions. (i did chmod 755)
-text file also have all permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message

Permission denied: '/home/anas/projects'

is pointing to the permissions of that directory. If too restrictive,
then the snmpd cannot go in there.

To solve the problem, do a

ls -ld /home/anas/projects

and that will give you a clue.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I also used chmod for the directory. Just a small follow-up question if you dont mind, If the shell script and python script can directly access the directory but snmp agent cant, does that mean that they are in different permission groups? Is it a good idea to give snmp agent higher permissions or should i handle this in another way?
Im still learning snmp so sorry for lots of questions.

Comment: It all depends on what user the SNMPD is running as. Google "Linux permissions" or somesuch for details.